# Why doesn't 'group by' function in my syntax work?

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, syntax, aggregate

I'm a beginner in SQL using Google BigQuery, and I wrote a syntax to find the best seller by 'price' and 'category' with some kind of 'status'. here's the syntax:

```
SELECT
 oi.product_id
, p.category as product_category
, DATE_TRUNC(oi.created_at, MONTH) AS month_order
, oi.status as status_order
, ROUND(SUM(oi.sale_price)) as subtotal_price
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.thelook_ecommerce.order_items` oi
LEFT JOIN
  `sql-project-376612.thelook_ecommerce.products` p
ON
  oi.product_id=p.id
WHERE DATE(oi.created_at) BETWEEN '2022-12-01' AND '2022-12-31'
  AND oi.status = 'Shipped'
  AND p.category IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY p.category
ORDER BY 5 DESC
```

please help me to find why Group By function didnt work? Thanks in advance, mate.

I've found the answer using excel because using sql can't :(

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT` - _except those who are arguments to set functions_.

Comment: I've been remove p.category from SELECT, but it still does not work

Answer (score 1):

You need to `GROUP BY` the columns that you use in `WHERE`:

```
SELECT
 oi.product_id
, p.category as product_category
, DATE_TRUNC(oi.created_at, MONTH) AS month_order
, oi.status as status_order
, ROUND(SUM(oi.sale_price)) as subtotal_price
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.thelook_ecommerce.order_items` oi
LEFT JOIN
  `sql-project-376612.thelook_ecommerce.products` p
ON
  oi.product_id=p.id
WHERE DATE(oi.created_at) BETWEEN '2022-12-01' AND '2022-12-31'
  AND oi.status = 'Shipped'
  AND p.category IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY oi.product_id
, p.category
, DATE_TRUNC(oi.created_at, MONTH)
, oi.status
ORDER BY 5 DESC
```

Comment: Does *columns that you use in WHERE* is a correct explanation ? Columns used in SELECT list should be listed as well in GROUP BY clause.